# Domain name without "www" results in 404 or "Under Construction" page in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, dns, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

I have two websites hosted in IIS 7.5 that use SSL and are bound to two different internal IP addresses. When I navigate to either of them without "www" (e.g. http://example.com), then I get a 404 error for Site A and an "Under Construction" page for Site B. When I go to the URL without "www" using a browser *outside* of the server, Site B shows an IIS 7 start page.

I have tried multiple configurations of DNS records and IIS rewrite rules, and still can't sort it out. I can ping both domain names (originally I could not ping a site without "www" and would get a DNS error). Now when I view `nslookup`, I can see that both www and non-www have the same IP address.

It seems like requests to the non-www domain name are getting to IIS since it returns a 404 page or IIS 7 start / construction page. **How do I properly redirect non-www requests to www?** The canonical domain name rule(s) in IIS did not work.

Answer (score 2):

It still sounds like you have some dns issues to work out. If you post your IP addresses, dns entries, and website bindings I'd be able to help sort it out. But to answer your other question about properly redirecting non-www requests to www, I would use a rewrite rule as follows:

```
<rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I won't have access to DNS entries until Monday. I tried the redirect rule, as well as a similar one to check where it *doesn't* match the "www" pattern, and neither worked. I'll share more in a chat next week if you're available. We have a unique internal IP address for each domain. The bindings for a given site use the same IP address with different ports (80, 443): Site A is xxx.xx.x.8, Site B is xxx.xx.x.15. I think you're correct that these are DNS issues, but I'll see Monday. nslookup shows that both domains use the same server and server IP, but the names have different addresses.